# How form validation/ data limitation of a vehicle_number and date using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

i dont include here the form input Etc. because my code is working. 
i want a form validation like this query is to select delivery table if "vehicle 1" appears on the database 5 times and on the same delivery date. alert an error that Vehicle 1 need to have a delivery 5 times only on that date."

**DATABASE:**
      vehicle_name | delivery_date 
      vehicle 1       8/29/2016
      vehicle 1       8/29/2016
      vehicle 1       8/29/2016
      vehicle 1       8/29/2016
      vehicle 1       8/29/2016

**on the 6th input**

       input: vehicle 1 
       input: 8/29/2016

**there is no problem in my inputs. i just want a validation that you cannot add any delivery anymore if "vehicle 1" exist 5 times on delivery table on 8/29/2016. HOW WILL I CODE THAT?"**

Controller

```
private function _validate()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['error_string'] = array();
    $data['inputerror'] = array();
    $data['status'] = TRUE;

    if($this->input->post('client_firstname') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'client_firstname';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'First name is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('client_lastname') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'client_lastname';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Last name is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('client_contact') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'client_contact';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Customer contact is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('client_address') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'client_address';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Address is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('tracking_no') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'tracking_no';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Tracking number is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }

    if($this->input->post('vehicle_id') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'vehicle_id';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Vehicle Assignation Required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }


    if($this->input->post('delivery_status') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'delivery_status';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Delivery status is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }


    if($this->input->post('delivery_date') == '')
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'delivery_date';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Delivery Date is required';
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
    }


    if($data['status'] === FALSE)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

on my script

```
function add_delivery()
{
save_method = 'add';
$('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
$('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
$('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
$('.modal-title').text('Add Delivery'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
}

function save()
{
$('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
$('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
var url;

if(save_method == 'add') {
    url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/delivery/ajax_add')?>";
    $('#btnSave').text('Add Delivery');
} else {
    url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/delivery/ajax_update')?>";
}

// ajax adding data to database
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
            alert('Successfully Added');
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('Save Delivery'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
        $('#btnSave').text('Save Delivery'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
});
```

}

Comment: what is the input variable names of  `vehicle 1` and `8/29/2016`?? please specify

Comment: @Spartan vehicle_name and delivery_date..

Comment: there is no problem in my inputs. i just want a validation that you cannot add any delivery anymore if "vehicle 1" exist 5 times on delivery table on 8/29/2016

Comment: is `delivery_date` manual input ??

Comment: @Spartan no i use datepicker so it will appear always like M/DD/YY like 8/29/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Model**

```
function getVeichleCount($vehicle_name, $delivery_date)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(id) FROM table_name WHERE vehicle_name = '$vehicle_name' AND delivery_date = $delivery_date ");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In Callback function**

```
$count = $this->model_name->getVeichleCount($vehicle_name, $delivery_date)[0];
if ($count >= 5) {
    # count already have 5 records
    # your error goes here
}
```

Comment: $vid = $this->input->post('vehicle_id');
   $dad = $this->input->post('delivery_date');   
        $count = $this->delivery_model->getVehicleCount($vid , $dad);
        $c = 5;

        if($count >= $c)
        {
            $data['inputerror'][] = 'vehicle_id';
            $data['error_string'][] = 'Appeared 5 times';
            $data['status'] = FALSE;
        }

Comment: Seems correct. Before add model code. use print r to check variable is passing the output

Comment: some error. i am going inside the if() even if 3>=5

Comment: No. It cant be. `echo $count` and post data

Comment: Array ( [count(delivery_id)] => 2 )  is the result.. returning a string output must only **2**  there is problem in returning the result

Comment: add that in controller below model calling method

Comment: i got a solution i return the num_rows() from getVehicleCount, by using SELECT delivery_id FROM delivery WHERE vehicle_id = '$vehicle_id'AND delivery_date = '$ddate' and $result = $query->num_rows(); return $result;  on controller,  $count = $this->delivery_model->getVehicleCount($vehicle_id, $delivery_date ); and it works.. thank you for this idea.